# Create document without source, based on parse sources

Tags: python-sphinx, docutils

With a sphinx extension, can I create additional sphinx pages not related to a specific source file?

source files:

```
foo.xml
bar.xml
```

output files:

```
foo.html
bar.html
wanted.html
```

The `wanted` file would be explicitly created by my extension, using info parsed from `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope its more clear.

Comment: It's still really not clear what your question is, and what it has to do with Python. If you're using some code to generate this, please share a minimal example of code that we can run and see what you're doing, and explain what it's missing or what is not working.

Comment: It's also really not clear how your foo, bar and toto XML trees are related to your document tree at the end. Please make that clear with a minimal but complete example where we can obviously see "oh, this 'asdf' from foo landed here in the results, and that 'qwer' from bar landed there in the results," etc.

Comment: I was being too specific, now I think its better.

Comment: "With a sphinx extension, can I create..." - Sphinx extensions are written in Python. Why did you remove the [python] tag? I think it is possible to do what you describe, but first please show us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck (see [mcve]).

Comment: I read a lot of documentation but I did not found anything about creating output without a corresponding source file.
I simply don't know where to start, and if this is even possible.